Expo EAS Build Fails: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'
I'm working on an Expo React Native project and recently upgraded to Expo SDK 52 ("expo": "^52.0.0"). After the upgrade, my EAS Build for Android started failing with the following error:

[mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.webp
[mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png:
Error: Duplicate resources

... (similar errors for other mipmap folders)
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "MyApp",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
     "android": {
      "versionCode": 15,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
  }
}

I don’t have both .png and .webp launcher icons in my project. Each launcher icon exists in only one format.
How can I resolve the duplicate resources error after upgrading to Expo SDK 52?

Could you fix this? I have the same error!
